# npm warnings when installing laravel bootstrap

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, yarnpkg

I was trying to use the preset bootstrap function and run npm install as required but i got this error message:

```
C:\Users\morte\Documents\NoStatic>php artisan preset bootstrap
Bootstrap scaffolding installed successfully.
Please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding.

C:\Users\morte\Documents\NoStatic>npm install
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: Popper changed home, find its new releases at @popperjs/core
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1053 packages from 491 contributors and audited 17274 packages in 11.831s

33 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I have never touched laravel before but the errors from nodejs seems weird. Im using windows 10. Should I ignore these errors or should i somehow try to fix them? I use the latest version of node.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your Laravel version?

Comment: I use laravel version 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the installed npm packages in `package.json` in Laravel installed directory.

Remove the existing popper package

```
npm remove bootstrap popper.js
// yarn remove bootstrap popper.js
```

Install latest package

```
npm i bootstrap @popperjs/core --save-dev
// yarn add bootstrap @popperjs/core --dev
```

This will pull the latest version of popper and bootstrap and the warning will disappear. You can ignore `fsevents` warning.

Comment: Hey again, thanks for your help :) It gave me some errors, as bootstrap isnt supported by the latest popperjs, but it was worth a try :) I'll just keep using the old popperjs :)

Comment: @Kh4zy, bootstrap still use popper 1.x version.

Answer (score 0):

The Popper.js warning is there just to inform the library consumers of the existence of newer releases of the project under a different package name.

Bootstrap still requires `popper.js@1` so you don't have to do anything, just ignore the message.

Answer (score 0):

**This solves the problem**

```
    npm remove bootstrap popper.js
    npm i bootstrap @popperjs/core --save-dev
```